# What is the most efficient method of detecting whether an object's content has changed and update the object? C#

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

**The Problem**

Often controller classes (MV**C**, MV**VM**, MV**P**) that manipulate views have access to a multitude of services. The purpose of one of these services is to update the controller classes with data that is pertinent to the controller.

Take this class for example:

```
public sealed class RestaurantInformation
{
    public IEnumerable<Networking.Models.ServerModels.Restaurant> NearestRestaurants { get; internal set; }
    public IEnumerable<Networking.Models.ServerModels.Restaurant> NewestRestaurants { get; internal set; }
    public IEnumerable<Networking.Models.ServerModels.Category> Categories { get; internal set; }
}
```

Whenever the service receives updated information from the network regarding Categories, NewestRestaurants or NearestRestaurants, it packages all of the data into an object which has the class type RestaurantInformation and sends it to the controller class to pass to the view.

I decided to put my C grade in my art GCSE to good use and construct diagrams to aid your understanding of my problem. (Apologies for what you are about to see.)

[image]

As you can now see, the flow is as follows:

1. The view loads which in turn calls the RestaurantViewControl.
2. The RestaurantViewControl then calls the RestaurantService to retrieve the new categories from the API.
3. The API returns the new categories to the RestaurantService. (You can see here the restaurant service now has a list that contains B).
4. The RestaurantService then notify's the RestaurantViewControl using the class above with the new list of categories!
5. We must now update the list of categories in the RestaurantViewControl in the most efficient way possible with the new items.

I am currently clearing the categories list and then replacing all the values with the new list. The two things I want to know are:

1. What is the most efficient way to detect a change in the Categories List object?
2. What is the most efficient way to update the categories list which may still contain objects that are completely valid in that list.

Comment: "best" is typically a matter of opinion and personal preference

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you have a straight forward issue. You will have a services layer that calls when you show the restaurant list page.

So your collectionView/listView just displays the list of items in the view cell based on that data. One example https://almirvuk.blogspot.com/2019/07/lets-play-with-collectionview-layouts.html?m=1

Usually you’ll just do a check for changes on the first time you visit the page, pull to refresh, or if you set up caching-after a set time when the cache expires.

Comment: Hi @Saameer I don't believe this answer is relevant, neither does it answer either of the questions stated above.

Comment: Ok let’s go one at a time. What did you mean by “ What is the most efficient way to detect a change in the Categories List object?” I answered-“ Usually you’ll just do a check for changes on the first time you visit the page, pull to refresh, or if you set up caching-after a set time when the cache expires.” @jamesmallon